# Better way to join two arrays of objects on two properties?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to combine two arrays of objects, based on two properties, and rewrite the names of other properties in the joined dataset.

This is what the datasets look like:

```
var xData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 18 },
   { row_id: 2, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 27 } ...
];
var yData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 48 },
   { row_id: 3, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 37 } ...
];
```

The properties I want to join on are the `row_id` and `date` properties, and I want to rewrite `cost` to `x_cost` and `y_cost` respectively. I also want to deal with missing values. So this is what I want to end up with:

```
var combinedData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', x_cost: 18, y_cost: 48 },
   { row_id: 2, date: '2013-04-01', x_cost: 27, y_cost: null },
   { row_id: 3, date: '2013-04-01', x_cost: null, y_cost: 37 } ...
];
```

This is my code right now. It's pretty horrible:

```
combineXAndYDatasets: function(xData, yData) {
    // Index both datasets by ID and date. 
    var x_indexed_by_id_and_date = {};
    xData.forEach(function(d) {
        var k = d.row_id + '_' + d.date;
        x_indexed_by_id_and_date[k] = d;
    });
    var y_indexed_by_id_and_date = {};
    yData.forEach(function(d) {
        var k = d.row_id + '_' + d.date;
        y_indexed_by_id_and_date[k] = d;
    });

    var combinedData = [];
    // Iterate over ydata, join with xdata if possible.
    for (var row_id in y_indexed_by_id_and_date) {
        var row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(y_indexed_by_id_and_date[row_id]));
        row.y_cost = +y_indexed_by_id_and_date[row_id].cost;
        if (row_id in x_indexed_by_id_and_date) {
            row.x_cost = +x_indexed_by_id_and_date[row_id].cost;
        } else {
            row.x_cost = null;
        }
        combinedData.push(row);
    }
    // Iterate over xdata, add anything that wasn't in ydata.
    for (var x_row_id in x_indexed_by_id_and_date) {
        if (!(x_row_id in y_indexed_by_id_and_date)) {
            var x_row = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x_indexed_by_id_and_date[x_row_id]));
            x_row.y = null;
            x_row.x = +x_row.cost;
            combinedData.push(x_row);
        }
    }
    return combinedData;
}
```

What can I do to make this less awful?

I'm using jQuery, and I could add e.g. Underscore if that would help.

Comment: Is `row_id` unique by itself? Or is it only the combination of `row_id` and `date` that makes up the primary key?

Comment: @MattBurland it's the combination that is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of `reduce` to reduce each array to a dictionary and then convert that dictionary back into an array. Something like this (vanilla JS, not IE 8 compatible out-of-the-box):

```js
var xData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 18 },
   { row_id: 2, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 27 }
];
var yData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 48 },
   { row_id: 3, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 37 }
];

var xDataDict = xData.reduce(function(p,c) {
    createDictionaryEntry(p,c,c.cost,null)
    return p;
},{});

xAndYDataDict = yData.reduce(function(p,c) {
    createDictionaryEntry(p,c,null,c.cost)
    return p;
}, xDataDict);


var combinedData = Object.keys(xAndYDataDict).map(function(key) { 
    return xAndYDataDict[key]; 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(combinedData));


function createDictionaryEntry(p,c,x_cost,y_cost) {
    var key = c.row_id + "-" + c.date;
    if (p[key]) {
        p[key].x_cost = p[key].x_cost || x_cost;
        p[key].y_cost = p[key].y_cost || y_cost;
    } else {
        p[key] = {
            row_id: c.row_id,
            date: c.date,
            x_cost: x_cost,
            y_cost: y_cost
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `combinedData` won't be in any guaranteed order, so if that's important, you can always `sort` it afterwards.

Using underscore:

```js
var xData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 18 },
   { row_id: 2, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 27 }
];
var yData = [ 
   { row_id: 1, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 48 },
   { row_id: 3, date: '2013-04-01', cost: 37 }
];

var xDataDict = _.reduce(xData, function(p,c) {
    createDictionaryEntry(p,c,c.cost,null)
    return p;
},{});

xAndYDataDict = _.reduce(yData,function(p,c) {
    createDictionaryEntry(p,c,null,c.cost)
    return p;
}, xDataDict);


var combinedData = _.map(Object.keys(xAndYDataDict),function(key) { 
    return xAndYDataDict[key]; 
});

alert(JSON.stringify(combinedData));


function createDictionaryEntry(p,c,x_cost,y_cost) {
    var key = c.row_id + "-" + c.date;
    if (p[key]) {
        p[key].x_cost = p[key].x_cost || x_cost;
        p[key].y_cost = p[key].y_cost || y_cost;
    } else {
        p[key] = {
            row_id: c.row_id,
            date: c.date,
            x_cost: x_cost,
            y_cost: y_cost
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to support IE8 though, I guess I could use Underscore's `_.reduce` to do this?

Comment: @Richard: Probably, you'd have to check if the syntax is the same or not. Otherwise, if you check out [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) they have a polyfill you can include to support older browsers. Or if you search around, you can find things like [this](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) that provide a bunch of shims to support older browsers.

Comment: @Richard: Ok, just added an underscore version.